# Can you bring a used TV into Nepal?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, electronic-items, nepal

Am I allowed to bring in a second-hand TV into Nepal?

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to?

Comment: There may be a difference between taking it with you, and sending it over, but I'm not sure if that applies to individuals or to institutions only. Nepal has had bad experiences with people dumping their inferior materials by way of 'donations', and has tightened the rules for imports. Anecdote from [Kopila Valley](http://www.BlinkNow.org), episodes [1](http://www.blinknow.org/journal/entry/the-luggage-saga-continues), [2](http://www.blinknow.org/journal/entry/update-from-china), [3](http://www.blinknow.org/journal/entry/apologies). Maybe you should actually contact customs and ask them.